# Automatically place sloped nodes on the outside of a path

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I was plaing around with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276665/triangles-inside-triangles-fractals-to-an-arbitrary-depth/276730#276730), I came across some unexpected behaviour when using the options `sloped` and `below` together. This code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \C in {1,...,5}
    { \draw[-latex] (\C*72-72:5) -- (\C*72:5) node[sloped, below, pos=0.66] {XYZ};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces a pentagram with nodes placed on all the sides, where the text is automatically rotated to never be upside down:

[image]

However, the two nodes with the red frame are not only rotated to be easily readable, but they now are also on the "wrong" side of the path. If I additionaly use the `allow upside down` option like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \C in {1,...,5}
    {   \draw[-latex] (\C*72-72:5) -- (\C*72:5) node[sloped, below, pos=0.66, allow upside down] {XYZ};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

then the nodes are on the "correct" side, but (as expected) upside down.

[image]

As I don't want to put `above` or `below` manually, is there a way to place the nodes upside and outside? Or is there probably a better choice than `below`, like some kind of key specifying "place the node on the right side when looking along the path"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `allow upside down` key sets `\ifpgfallowupsidedownattime` which is used in the basic layer transformations so it is difficult to influence this behaviour without some fairly major hacking.

So it is probably best to set the node anchor manually conditionally using the angle of the line, which is quite easy to get in this case:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \C  in {1,...,5}
  \draw[-latex] (\C*72-72:5) -- (\C*72:5) 
     node[sloped, pos=0.66, anchor={\C*72 > 180 ? 90 : 270}] {XYZ};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's a really clever solution!

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry I overlook your second code)

Instead of `sloped` system, you can use `auto` and an optional `swap`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \foreach \C in {1,...,5}
        \draw[-latex](\C*72-72:5)--(\C*72:5)node[sloped,auto,swap,pos=.66]{XYZ};
}
\end{document}
```

The question is that Ti*k*Z does not know how to handle absolutely vertical line. So you might want to rotate it slightly

[image]

```
    \draw[rotate=3,-latex](\C*72-72:5)--(\C*72:5)node[rotate=3,sloped,auto,swap,pos=.66]{XYZ};
```

Now it is `\C`-independent.

---

If one finds the rotation annoying, here is a solution:

Basically, `auto` is nothing but an anchor-choosing procedure. It chooses an anchor at edge if the input angle is about a multiple of `90`. It chooses an anchor at corner if the input angle is far from multiples of `90`.

So the problem of mixing `auto` and `sloped` is that for vertical lines, `auto` chooses `east` or `west` and it ends up with nodes overlaying the line. What we want here is a stupider `auto` which chooses either `south` or `north`.

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@install@auto@anchor@leftsloped{\let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\tikz@auto@anchor@on\def\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{leftsloped}}
\def\tikz@install@auto@anchor@rightsloped{\let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\tikz@auto@anchor@on\def\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{rightsloped}}
\def\tikz@auto@anchor@leftsloped{\tikz@auto@pre\tikz@auto@anchor@sloped\tikz@auto@post}
\def\tikz@auto@anchor@rightsloped{\tikz@auto@pre\tikz@auto@anchor@prime@sloped\tikz@auto@post}
\def\tikz@auto@anchor@sloped{
    \ifdim\pgf@x<0pt
        \def\tikz@anchor{north}
    \else
        \def\tikz@anchor{south}
    \fi
}
\def\tikz@auto@anchor@prime@sloped{
    \ifdim\pgf@x<0pt
        \def\tikz@anchor{south}
    \else
        \def\tikz@anchor{north}
    \fi
}
\tikzset{
    auto sloped/.style={auto=leftsloped,sloped},
    auto sloped'/.style={auto=rightsloped,sloped},
}
\tikz
    \foreach \C in {1,...,5}
        \draw[-latex](\C*72-72:5)--(\C*72:5)node[auto sloped,pos=.66]{XYZ};

\tikz
    \foreach \C in {1,...,5}
        \draw[-latex](\C*72-72:5)--(\C*72:5)node[auto sloped,pos=.66]{XYZ};

\tikz
    \foreach \C in {1,...,10}
        \draw[-latex](\C*36-18:5)--(\C*36+18:5)node[auto sloped,pos=.66]{XYZ};

\tikz
    \foreach \C in {1,...,10}
        \draw[-latex](\C*36-18:5)--(\C*36+18:5)node[auto sloped',pos=.66]{XYZ};
```

It works with arbitrary curves

[image]

```
\tikz\draw(0,0)..controls+(right:3.5cm)and+(right:3.5cm)..(0,3)node foreach\p in{0,0.01,...,1}[pos=\p,auto sloped',red]{X};
```

[image]

```
\tikz\draw(0,0)..controls+(5,-3)and(-2,6)..(3,3)node foreach\p in{0,0.01,...,1}[pos=\p,auto sloped',red]{!};
```